# How to verify that app has been instrumented in calabash?

Tags: android, ruby, xamarin, calabash

I want to automate Xamarin android app for which I am planning to use Calabash automation tool. I am new to this tool.

I have successfully installed Ruby, Ant and SDK on my system.

After running the calabash-android run  command, I am getting the following log:-

```
2014-07-25 12:13:42 - Installing: C:/Users/<path to apk>
4150 KB/s (11783001 bytes in 2.772s)
2014-07-25 12:13:50 -   pkg: /data/local/tmp/xxx.apk


Success

2014-07-25 12:13:51 - Starting test server using:

2014-07-25 12:13:51 - "D:\softwares\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk/platform
-tools/adb.exe" -s 3230a28fb94fb09b shell am instrument -e target_package com.xxx.android -e main_activity xxx.app.android.activities.StartActivity -e test_
server_port 7102 -e class sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.InstrumentationBacken
d com.xxx.android.test/sh.calaba.instrumentationbackend.CalabashInstrumentatio
nTestRunner

2014-07-25 12:13:53 - It looks like your app is no longer running.

It could be because of a crash or because your test script shut it down.

2014-07-25 12:13:54 - Checking if instrumentation backend is ready

2014-07-25 12:13:54 - Is app running? true

2014-07-25 12:13:54 - Instrumentation backend not yet ready

2014-07-25 12:13:57 - Checking if instrumentation backend is ready

2014-07-25 12:13:57 - Is app running? true

2014-07-25 12:13:57 - Instrumentation backend is ready!

2014-07-25 12:13:57 - Checking client-server version match...

2014-07-25 12:13:57 - Action: version - Params:

2014-07-25 12:13:57 - Result:'{"bonusInformation":[],"message":"0.5.0","success"
:true}'

2014-07-25 12:13:57 - Client and server versions match. Proceeding...
```

I just want to confirm that whether my apk is instrumented or not? Is there any way to verify that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your .apk path and run below command and see weather your app launch or not.

```
calabash-android console path-to-your-app.apk
```

After this the irb console session should start

```
start_test_server_in_background
```

**your app should launch by the command itself.**

Comment: The above mentioned steps are working for me. Even after that the error "android.test did not get installed. Reason: 'Aborted '. Aborting! (RuntimeError)
  ./features/support/app_installation_hooks.rb:19:in `Before'
  Will not start test server because of previous failures. (RuntimeError)
"